# How to deserialize unknown members with YamlDotNet

Tags: yamldotnet

This code does not work because

> YamlDotNet.Core.YamlException: 'Property 'unknown1' not found.

How do I configure this correctly (if it is possible at all)

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using YamlDotNet.RepresentationModel;
using YamlDotNet.Serialization;
using YamlDotNet.Serialization.NamingConventions;

var input = @"
Name: John
Count: 34
unknown1:
  xyz: value1
  abc: value2
unknown2: foo
");

var serializer = new SerializerBuilder()
    .WithNamingConvention(PascalCaseNamingConvention.Instance)
    .Build();
var deserializer = new DeserializerBuilder()
    .WithNamingConvention(PascalCaseNamingConvention.Instance)
    .Build();
    

public class Person {

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Count { get; set; }

    // this is not a regular property, this is to record all unknown members from the yaml.
    // and when serializing, the content should be serialized again on the same level
    // as Name und Count. 
    public Dictionary<string, string> UnknownProperties { get; set; }
}
```

If it would work UnknownProperties should contain the following:

`{"unknown1", "xyz: value1\nabc: value2"} {"unknown2", "foo"}`

alternatively: `Dictionary<string, object> UnknownProperties`

`{"unknown1", {{"xyz","value1"},{"abc", "value2"}}} {"unknown2", "foo"}`

The structure of unknown1, unknown2 is not known at this time.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking something like [`JsonExtensionData`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeExtensionData.htm). There is [an open issue on this topic](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/issues/593).

As a workaround, you could deserialize to a dictionary:

```cs
var yaml = "..."; // the yaml data from some source
var myModel = deserializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>();
```

Then you'll be able to access `Name` and `Count` from the dictioary:

```cs
myModel["Name"] = "new name";
var onlyNameChanged = serializer.Serialize(myModel);
```

If you change any of the values, when you serialize back to yaml, the values will be persisted, and any extra properties will be maintained.

Comment: thx, in the meantime I created a fork and implemented everything I need myself ;-)